# Image is being loaded from nowhere

Tags: html, css

i have a problem while designing my web page in asp.net MVC5.
i'm designing my login and registration page through a file called style.css.

in the begining i put a background image for testing and kept working with the same for few days.now when i'm putting my desired image in its Images file and trying to load it first time of running app its working but when refresh it go to other page it's not being load but the image i worked on previously is appearing even that picture i already deleted from my project plus i checked each and every code its not being called from anywhere.i tried every possible way now looking for help her. For further detail i'm providing the code.

style.css

```css
body {
 
   background:pink ;
    background-size: cover;
    width:auto;
 text-align:center;
}
```

after refreshing page the background changes from pink to the previous background.

Comment: Sounds like a browser caching issue. Have you tried viewing these pages in a different browser you seldom use, or one you haven't used yet to view this project? You can also use chrome's "Guest User" or "Incognito" (Ctrl+Shift+N).

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works.